# Django: authenticate() returns none except one case

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-authentication

So i am stuck at a point in my project. I am trying to create users and I have extended User model using the OneToOnefield method as recommended in Documentation to create a user profile. There is no problem in creation of the user as all the details are correctly stored in both the auth_user and appname_userprofile table.

The problem I get is when I try to login with any user stored in the auth_user table. Except one case( which i created before creating the userProfile model). So in my auth_user Table the pass for this one case is encoded but for the remaining cases it's plain text.

Here is my function handling the view -

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.body)
        username = request.POST.get('id_username')
        password = request.POST.get('id_password')
        print(username, password)
        try:
            import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            print('This is ',user)

            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
            else:
                return redirect('fileupload')
            print('This is ',user).... some more code
```

Now when i pass the credentials for this one case and try to authenticate. the login works(except my code gets stuck at some later point because this user doesn't have any profile).

When i pass the credentials for user created after creating the UserProfile model. The

> authenticate(username=username, password=password)

function returns

> None

I have included this in my settings.py -

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

This is my model -

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    # email = models.EmailField()
    department = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    industry_segment = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated_by = models.IntegerField(null=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.userprofile.save()
```

This is how i am saving the users -

```
def user_view(request):
    print(request.user)
    if request.is_ajax():

        print(request.user)

        data = json.load(request)
        u_name = data['txtfirstName'] + " " + data['txtlastName']             




user=User(username=u_name,password='test123',email=data['txtemailId'])
                user.save()
                # userprofile= UserProfile.objects.create(user=request.user)
                user.userprofile.contact_no = data['txtcontactNo']
                # user.userprofile.email = data['txtemailId']
                user.userprofile.department = data['txtdeptvalue']
                user.userprofile.status = data['txtstatusvalue']
                user.userprofile.industry_segment = 'Software'
                user.userprofile.created_at = datetime.datetime.now()
                user.userprofile.created_by = request.user.id
                user.userprofile.updated_at = datetime.datetime.now()
                user.userprofile.updated_by = request.user.id
                user.save()
```

ignore the formatting of this code... but it is working

So can anyone help me with the authentication problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not create users like that. The password will not be hashed, so will never match in authenticate. You must always use the `create_user` manager method.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username=u_name, password='test123', email=data['txtemailId'])
```